# cpp python boost integration cause system load anomalies

Tags: python, c++, boost

I have a project basd on c++14, and i try to integrate some python code using python boost 1.58

Once the python got initialized with the command

```
Py_Initialize();
```

we detected some short hangs on some other threads. i though in the beginning that it was due to pythons garbage collector, but i ruled it out by disabling it.

the system is highly tuned (each treads have its own core using affinity )  so every 'glitch' is notable.
anyone got an idea what can case it?